# Where is the bash_profile in SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, bash, suse

I could not find the my bash profile which running automatically after login.

I already checked /home/(username) with ls -a.

I am sure there is bash profile because when i echo $somethings, it response.

Could you help me ?

Comment: It's just `.profile`, if it's not there just make it.

Comment: i could not file .profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` or even maybe `~/.bashrc`, which isn't a "profile", but might be run after login (see INVOCATION in `man bash` to understand when and in what order bash reads its startup files). If the file doesn't exist, you can create it.

There're also the system-wide `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: none of them exist. What i want is should be easy. If i add new user account, where is the default .profile of it?

Comment: @sezercan: If it's not there, create it in the user's home directory.

Comment: where is the user's home. Should i create new user home?

Comment: @sezercan: It should be created when you add the user. Check `/home/username`.

Comment: i am using SuSe. When i login my user account and when i do $HOME, it shows /home/oragent but there is no like that directory. So i created it. So, if i create new .bash_profile under this directory it will automatically read the profile ?

Comment: @sezercan: How did you add the user? Try creating the profile with a simple `echo 'Profile found'` to test it.

Comment: i added with 'useradd' and after added user i defined 'passwd username'. When i login, it reads some other profile. Not the /home/username profile

Comment: @sezercan: Did you use the `-D` with useradd?

Comment: @sezercan: Why? It would do lots of stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

After `/etc/profile`, the `bash` shell (assuming it's either an interactive login shell or run with the `--login` option) looks for the first file in this set (in your home directory) that exists and is readable:

- `~/.bash_profile`;
- `~/.bash_login`; and
- `~/.profile`.

Hence you may not even *have* a `.bash_profile`.

The rules are actually very complex, depending on the type of the shell and the various arguments you give to it. If you want to know in detail, have a look in the `INVOCATION` section of the `bash` `man` page.

Comment: I checked /etc/profile. There are hundreads of codes there and i could not find my user profile. What i want is should be easy. If i add new user account, where is the default .profile of it?

Comment: @sezercan, that's the system-wide profile. Your *user* profile will be one of the three mentioned in the bullet list (the first that exists and is readable). If none of the three exist, none will be run.

Comment: @paxdiablo i can create the .bash_profile's but where is my user's home in suse. On Oracle EL It is in /home/username